# Login and register on the same page with Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I would like to know if it's possible to custom the user's login page  with 2 forms, with one form with the login compoment and one with the registry compoment.

If you have examples, I'm willing to try.

Best regards

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult, just enable the [user registration](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_user-registration) and take a look at how the registration form is implemented. Then, add your custom login theme for the realm , add the form and the required logic to send it.